# Why I failed to compare date with moment js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

My javascript code like this :

```
let requestDate = sendDate + ' ' + sendTime + ':00'
requestDate = moment(requestDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
let currentDate = moment().add(3, 'h').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")

console.log(requestDate)
console.log(currentDate)
console.log('test')
if( requestDate <= currentDate){
    console.log('1')
}
else {
    console.log('2');
}
```

On the console seems like this :

[image]

Why is the result of console.log showing 2?

From my code, it should be result of console.log showing 1

Comment: What is sendDate and sendTime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a moment object (i.e.: requestDate) with a string (i.e.: currentDate).

You can see this in the following snippet:

```js
let requestDate = '07-09-2017' + ' ' + '12' + ':00'
requestDate = moment(requestDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
let currentDate = moment().add(3, 'h').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")

console.log('requestDate is: ' + typeof(requestDate) + ' its    AND the value is: ' + requestDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"))
console.log('currentDate is: ' + typeof(currentDate) + ' its    AND the value is: ' + currentDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You have two options.

**First option**

Compare string dates. In this case you can use [Query functions](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/). In your case you can use: isSameOrAfter.

Therefore, you can change this line:

```
if( requestDate <= currentDate){
```

to:

```
if( moment(currentDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").isSameOrAfter(moment(requestDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"))) {
```

```js
let requestDate = moment();
requestDate = moment(requestDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
let currentDate = moment().add(3, 'h').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")

console.log(requestDate)
console.log(currentDate)
console.log('test')
if( moment(currentDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").isSameOrAfter(moment(requestDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"))) {
    console.log('1')
}
else {
    console.log('2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**The second option** is to compare moment objects and use **.format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")** only when you need to print the values.

```js
let requestDate = moment();
requestDate = moment(requestDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
let currentDate = moment().add(3, 'h');

console.log(requestDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"))
console.log(currentDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"))
console.log('test')
if( requestDate <= currentDate){
    console.log('1')
}
else {
    console.log('2');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change current date to same format as request date. Currently, request date is moment object, and current date is a date.

You can use the snippet below.

```js
    let sendDate = "07-09-2017";
    let sendTime = "17:05";
    let requestDate = sendDate + ' ' + sendTime + ':00'
    requestDate = moment(requestDate, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
    let currentDate = moment(moment().add(3, 'h'), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")

    console.log(requestDate.toDate())
    console.log(currentDate.toDate())
    console.log('test')
    if( requestDate.toDate() <= currentDate.toDate()){
        console.log('1')
    }
    else {
        console.log('2');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```